# How do i use JavaScript to take the input from a text box to a variable then print the value of a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to take the value of a text box and put it with a variable, then print the value of the variable as text on the page when a button is pressed. I'm using JavaScript and not using the form tag. So, how do I do this with what I have?

my code:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("I1");
var y = document.getElementById("I2");
var z = x+y;

document.getElementById("B2").onclick = function myFunction2(){
  documen.getElementById("H2").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to show your "*[mcve]*" HTML code for this question, in addition to the JavaScript (incidentally, you've got `documen` instead of `document`, which is a syntax error). As a new contributor you may also benefit from reading the "*[ask]*" guidance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("B2").onclick = function myFunction2(){
 var x = Number(document.getElementById("I1").value);
 var y = Number(document.getElementById("I2").value);
 var z = x+y;
  document.getElementById("H2").innerHTML = z;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="I1" value="" /> + 
<input type="text" id="I2" value="" /> = 
<button id="B2">
?
</button>
<span id="H2">
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. it works very well for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you'll simply want to grab the `.innerHTML` from your `<textarea>`, and assign that to `x`. Also note that you have `documen` instead of `document` inside of your click function.

Note that you're probably also looking to output `z` rather than `x`. This will only work (the way you expect) if both `x` and `y` are integers, so it's also a good idea to run `parseInt()` over the two values.

Here's a working example:

```js
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("I1").innerHTML);
var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("I2").innerHTML);
var z = x + y;

document.getElementById("B2").onclick = function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("H2").innerHTML = z;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="I1">1</textarea>
<br />
<div id="I2">2</div>
<br />
<button id="B2">Button</button>
<br />
<br />
<div id="H2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are `I1` and `I2` the ids of your textbox? because to get the inside text you need to use

```
var x = document.getElementById("I1").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rely on the `value` attribute of the textarea instead of its `innerHTML` attribute, and fetch that in the click event handler of the button.

```js
   

    document.getElementById("B2").onclick = function() {
     var x = document.getElementById("I1").value;
 document.getElementById("H2").innerHTML = x;
    }
```

```html
<textarea id="I1">1</textarea>
<br />
<button id="B2">Button</button>
<br />
<br />
<div id="H2"></div>
```